# Write methods to test for average grades in java

Tags: java

I'm writing code for homework and I got stuck.

The homework is to write a program to get the average of 10 grades that the user inputs.

I got most of it I believe, but in the `averageGrades` method when I try to declare `average` it wont let me.

This is what I have:

```
public class Averagegrades 
{
    public int min, max;
    double average; 

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        double sum = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] gradesarray = new int[10];

        System.out.println("Please enter the 10 test grades: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < gradesarray.length; i++)
        {            
            gradesarray[i] = scan.nextInt();

            if(gradesarray[i] > 100)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number within 0 - 100: ");
                gradesarray[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("These are the grades you entered: " +
            Arrays.toString(gradesarray));
        System.out.println("You have entered " + gradesarray.length + " grades");

        for(double num : gradesarray)
        {
            sum = sum + num;
        }

        System.out.println("This is the sum " + sum);
    }

    public double averageGrades()
    {
        average = sum / (double) gradesarray.length;
    }
```

Comment: If the compile is telling you of an error and you're stuck **post the full error message here**. But looks like you're trying to use a variable, `sum` that is not visible in the scope of the averageGrades method.

Comment: i declared it in the class. is that not it?

Comment: `sum` isn't in the same scope so it cannot be used in the method averageGrades

Comment: Move sum and gradesarray to the class level scope.  Currently visibility is only within `main`  Probably needs to be static

Comment: @DennisKim I missed the line, sorry about that :)

Comment: You did **not** declare `sum` in the class. It's been declared in and is only visible within the main method.

Comment: ahh. let me try that. thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so I declared it in the class. and the 2nd for loop in the main is saying the variable sum hasn't been initialized.

Comment: well initialise it then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this will let you declare avg. The problem is that the method averageGrades could not find sum or gradesarray because those two variables were declared in the main method, and thus not visible to the method.

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averagegrades 
{
public int min, max;
double average; 
static double sum;
static int[] gradesarray;

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    sum = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    gradesarray = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Please enter the 10 test grades: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < gradesarray.length; i++)
    {            
        gradesarray[i] = scan.nextInt();
        if(gradesarray[i] > 100)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number within 0 - 100: ");
            gradesarray[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("These are the grades you entered: "+
            Arrays.toString(gradesarray));
    System.out.println("You have entered "+gradesarray.length+" grades");

    for(double num : gradesarray)
    {
        sum = sum + num;
    }
    System.out.println("This is the sum "+sum);
}

public double averageGrades()
{
    average = sum / (double) gradesarray.length;
    return average ;
}
```

Alternative you could have also done...

```
public double averageGrades(int sum, int[] gradesarray)
{
  average = sum / (double) gradesarray.length; 
  return average ;
}
```

and then when calling the method...

```
averageGrades(sum, gradesarray);
```

By doing this you wouldnt have to move sum and gradesarray declaration outside of the the main method.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your sum variable is restricted to the main method, however you are utilising the sum variable in the averageGrade method, which lies outside of the main method.

To overcome this, declare the sum variable such that its scope covers the whole class. Declare the sum variable next to the *min*,*max* and *average* variables.

The exact same issue occurs for the integer array object. I suggest you read up on *Variable Scope*.

---

For more information on variable scope, check out: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm